# Query List Item in sharepoint using CAML queries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml, sharepoint-api

I have a list with three columns 1)Title,2) LoginUser 3)ParentSiteAccess. If a particular user is logged in then i need to fetch the values of the third column(i.e ParentSiteAccess).
I am using the below query to get it.

```
query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='LoginUser'/><Value Type='Text'>" + userName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                    query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef name='ParentSiteAccess'/><FieldRef name='LoginUser'/>";
                    query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

But i am not getting with this approach. Can anybody give me a valid solution?

Comment: Is `LoginUser` really a text field? Or is it a people chooser field?

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks well-formed, but without access to your environment it's very difficult to debug. A common problem is the columns' display names don't match their internal names.

The best thing I can tell you is to get a copy of a handy, free program called [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx). The 2007 version works fine with SP 2010.

Connect using "SharePoint Web Services" if you're not on the same box as your SharePoint install. If you are, either the "Object Model" or "Web Services" option will work.

Once logged in, point to your list and use the UI to build your query. The nicest thing about it is that you get to pick columns by their display name, but it builds the query using their internal names. It's a quick way to experiment with a query and get immediate feedback about what it returns.

When you get a query that works, just copy it out of the utility's window and into your code.